# What is TinyPG and how does it work?

Tags: c#, compiler-compiler, tinypg

What is TinyPG and how does it work? I know its a "compiler-compiler" but how do I get started and create my own compiler in C#?

Answer (score 8):

I've understood approximately how you use it, and here's a brief.

[TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/TinyPG.aspx) is a complete compiler-compiler IDE, with a Windows GUI for RegExp, EBNF and C#/VB. The following outlines the procedure of developing your own "compiler" within TinyPG:

You define Terminals using [Regular Expressions.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)

- You write these ReyExps within TinyPG, which basically extracts tokens from the input source code.
- RegExps are natively supported in .NET which means that even your generated "compiler" code uses .NET's RegExps.

You define Non-terminals and parser rules in [Extended BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) meta-syntax.

- You write EBNF within TinyPG, to describe the language of your choice.
- Some free [BNF Grammers](http://www.devincook.com/GOLDParser/grammars/index.htm) that describe modern programming languages.

You define the compiler in Managed code.

- You write C#/VB code within TinyPG, to convert the tokens into an output of your choice.
- One C#/VB code block per BNF grammer rule only.
- TinyPG can compile and run your "tokenizer + parser + complier" using the commandline compiler.

TinyPG generates C# code for your new "compiler".

- Generates a [parse-tree](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Parser_Flow.gif) from inputted source code, using your RegEx along with your EBNF.
- Translates this parse-tree into an output, using your C#/VB code.

You develop the front-end of your compiler in C# or VB.NET.

- A basic front end would invoke the generated C# classes with an input file, and display the output.

---

To begin, you can open the "simple expression2.tpg" file within the provided Samples of TinyPG to see a demo of a calculator "compiler".